# Azure | HDInsight Spark with ADLS and edge node

Tags: azure, apache-spark, azure-hdinsight

I created a Spark cluster with ADLS as default storage. It got created successfully. I am able to SSH to head node and login over Ambari. I am trying to create edge node over Spark but landing into error (internal Server Error). Detail trace is given below.

```
{
  "code": "InternalServerError",
  "message": "{\"status\":500,\"message\":\"Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint \\u0027UQ_TenantId_PartialDomainName_PublicPort\\u0027. Cannot insert duplicate key in object \\u0027dbo.IaasClusterApplicationEndpoints\\u0027. The duplicate key value is (1723971, hdisedpdev012-wa2.apps, 443).\"}"
}
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Could you re-check the properties passed in the Azure Resource Manager template to add an empty edge node to an existing cluster?

**Note:** I’m able to add edge node to an existing cluster with Azure Resource Manager template in the Azure Portal.

Detailed steps are mentioned in the article “[Add an edge node to an existing cluster](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/hdinsight-apps-use-edge-node#add-an-edge-node-to-an-existing-cluster)”.